# Can regular expressions be used with the Wikipedia API?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I have to do a lot of queries in several Wikipedia editions to find information that is not in DBpedia (for example, number of words in the Wikipedia page). From a word, such as "Paris", I would like to get with certainty the Wikipedia page of the French capital, not that of Paris in Ontario. I am therefore obliged to use the categories in my queries, like this:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=json&srsearch=paris+incategory:Departments_of_France](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=json&srsearch=paris%20incategory:Departments_of_France)

Problem : the Wikipedia categories are inconsistent. The ideal for me would be to be able to use as category a Regex, like "contain the word France".

I searched in the API documentation for hours without being able to understand how to do this. Any help or suggestion would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a search expression like `insource:/\[\[Category:[^\]]{0,32}France]]/`. ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=Paris%20insource%3A%2F%5C%5B%5C%5BCategory%3A%5B%5E%5C%5D%7C%5D%7B0%2C32%7DFrance(%5C%7C%7C%5D%5D)%2F)) See [Help:CirrusSearch#Regular expression searches](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:CirrusSearch#Regular_expression_searches) (the wildcard length limit seems to be necessary to avoid timeouts).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Tgr ! I had consulted this page of the documentation without being able to reproduce the examples. I still can not manage it. "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=json&srsearch=Lyon+insource:/\[\[Category:[^\]]*France]]/" returns a regex timeout. Could you provide a real example, please ?

Comment: [Here you go.](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=json&srsearch=Lyon+insource:/\[\[Category:[^\]]{0,32}France]]/)

Comment: Not sure how to escape the link correctly in markdown; the URL is `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=json&srsearch=Lyon+insource:/\[\[Category:[^\]]{0,32}France]]/` (added a length limit on the wildcard part to avoid regex timeout)

Comment: This particular query returns no results, but I understand the logic now, so I accept your answer. +1 for the idea of first querying Wikidata, although I'm still a little afraid of the Sparql endpoints traditional slowness.

Comment: Giot some kind of invisible Unicode junk mixed in there. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=Lyon+insource%3A%2F%5C%5B%5C%5BCategory%3A%5B%5E%5C%5D%7C%5D%7B0%2C32%7DFrance(%5C%7C%7C%5D%5D)%2F) is the correct query URL. Although as you can see from the results, this doesn't really solve the problem of finding multiple things.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Tgr. I see that Regexes searches are very slow ... I'm going to take a look at [Quarry](https://quarry.wmflabs.org/), which looks promising. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, probably better suited to your use case, is to use the Wikidata Query Service. Text search capabilities are limited (but it does not sound like you actually need them) and the syntax is more complicated (SPARQL + you need to get an idea of what property conventions Wikidata has) but you can express things like "in France".

- [All articles about something called "Paris"](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23Articles%20about%20things%20called%20%27Paris%27%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3Farticle%20%3FitemDescription%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%27Paris%27%40en%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20%3B%0A%09%09%09schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)
- [Same search limited to "in France"](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23Articles%20about%20things%20called%20%27Paris%27%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3Farticle%20%3FitemDescription%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%27Paris%27%40en%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP17%20wd%3AQ142%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20%3B%0A%09%09%09schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

(Mouse over the Pxx/Qxx things for info.)